# Loading SMS in doInBackgroung too slow

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-contentresolver

Hi I am developing an android app where I am trying to load sms from built in SMS app. This loading is too slow and it almost takes 10- 15 seconds to load all sms. I am laoding SMS in
doInBackground as below

```
private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Boolean> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Myapp.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override   
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) 
    {
        //fetching values from built-in message 
        getSMS();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean success) 
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                adapter = new SmsAdapter(EaseSms.this, listOfmessages); 
                smslist.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the getSMS() method is as below

```
public void getSMS()
{
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, new String[] {"*"}, null, null, "date desc");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
            snippet = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
            recipient_ids = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("recipient_ids"));

                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses"), null, "_id = " + recipient_ids, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                r_address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")); 
                Uri Nameuri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(r_address));  
                Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(Nameuri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,PhoneLookup._ID},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+r_address+"'",null,null);

                if(cs.getCount()>0)
                {
                    while (cs.moveToNext()) 
                    {
                        contactName = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        contactID = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    contactID = "01234567890";
                    contactName = r_address;
                }
                cs.close(); 
                c.close(); 
               addtomap();
        }
cursor.close();}
}
```

Is it possible to load some 10 SMS onPreExecute and continue loading other in doInBackground ? I tried something similar. But it dint work . Can anybody guide me to resolve this slow loading.

Please Help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Cursor Adapter, instead of trying to read all the sms first and then displaying them. Cursor adapter loads data as required or you can say on demand, this will solve your issue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

To Elaborate it further

```
public class SimpleCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;


    /**This is your constructor, Just pass it the cursor which you got from querying 
     * SMS database
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param c
     */

    public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
    }






    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        /** 
         * Write here code for binding you view to data form cursor
         * 
         * Just like any other adapter, fetch all the columns details you want
         * and set those values properly
         */


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        /**
         * Just inflate your child view layout and return it to system
         */

          View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.<YOUR_VIEW_NAME>, parent, false);
          return v;
    }

}
```

Thats it, once you done with above mentioned things, from your activity just get an cursor 
from sms db, create an instance of this adapter and just like any set it to your list view.

Comment: Sorry was on leave and couldnt reply back to you.  Can u guide me through any of links or projects using cursor adapter loading SMS.

Comment: Its very simple and easy to implement, just like any other adapter but only source of data changed to database. you can check following link for mre information about using them.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: ok. trying it out. If u have any sample project or link for SMS cursorAdapter do please share